# In my gradle shown below, can I remove from code testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' before publishing application?

Tags: android, gradle, publishing

In android studio, can I remove from code:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
```

before publishing application?

```
dependencies {
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can move them
and don't forget remove

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.networksecurity"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    //testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

and test folder(..\app\src\test)(..\app\src\androidTest)

Comment: why? is there any problem to run app without these test implementation codes? Thanks

Comment: no problem,these implementation only build in debug buildTypes

Comment: Ok, I want to remove these lines becouse I´ve finished testing my developing app and I want to publish it now, but I haven´t seen nothing in https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html about removing this lines, that´s why I made this question

Comment: because when you publish you app these implementation  will auto remove

Comment: and these implementations uses dex 64K allocation memory?